# How to run go generate on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go

I am using http://github.com/tmthrgd/go-bindata to embed static files and templates within Go executable file. It requires to run `go generate` to run a Go code that read each file and write binary representation as standard go file. `go generate` have to be fired before build process.
Is there a chance to configure Heroku to handle this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`go generate` should be run locally while developing, not on heroku. If you run it on heroku it will lead to very hard to debug issues. If `go generate` has unexpected results you wont be able to easily inspect this.

You could run `go generate` with a tool like [modd](https://github.com/cortesi/modd) or with a git hook.
Having the results of `go generate` tracked by git also means that you can track which changes affected generated code.

In a language like ruby it might be customary to run `bundle install` on the server and omit dependencies from git. For go programs this is not so. Dependencies should be vendored and tracked by git. Same for generated code.

The rest is not at all advised for this case and I would never do something like this.

- fork the go heroku buildpack
- add a line to run `go generate`
- use your modified go heroku buildpack
- deploy your app

[around this line](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/c11f285fa49bf545a63bbd6331192937d89eec2d/bin/compile#L421)

[more on buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)